# Lightning | Remove optional lookup filters

Tags: lookup

Is there any way to remove the optional filter in lookup fields in lightning as we have in classic?

Comment: Your question is right. In Classsic when we do search and open pop-up window, we see option of removing filter, but in lightning no such option exist.

Answer (score 4):

I think the people above have not well read your question. Indeed what you are asking is not supported in Lightning:

> **Admin-Defined Related and Dependent Lookup Filters Can’t Be Made Optional** Once added, all lookup filters are required, even if admins
>   specify them as optional in Setup. There’s no Show all results view
>   for users. User-defined lookup filter fields aren’t supported.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_search.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between clasic and lightning, since the field setup pages are still the same in lightning. Lookupfilters are serverside backend logic and not related to the Lightning Functionality.

This is the Lookup Field view in Lightning and it's completely similar to what we see in Clasic:
[image]

Comment: OP is asking to remove optional filter when searching the record in lightning, because same  classic provide this capability `Results are narrowed down by criteria set by the administrator.Show all results
` and in lightning lookup  record search no such option is available.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the lookup filter with some criteria to select the optional checkbox

[image]

Comment: User has enabled the Optional Lookup filter and expecting the same in lightning as it appear in classic lookup search. When OPtional lookup filter is enabled we see this text in lookup search window `Results are narrowed down by criteria set by the administrator.Show all results`. While no such option in lookup search window in lightning.